# What is Best solution to store temp modal data if there is file in model (.Net Core)

Tags: .net-core

I have application to work with customers, in add new customer page there is option to attach files related to customer after add file I want to display that in Grid because he can add multi files after that he can save customer data with files in DB.

My question is what is best solution to add data model as Temp after receive data in Action, may be after add some files he will cancel request or may be he can go to other page.

I try to use session but field because there is IFormFile field.

The following is my model

```
public class CustomerFileViewModel
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string FileType { get; set; }
public IFormFile DataFiles { get; set; }
}
```

The following is my Action in Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddFileTempItem(CustomerFileViewModel model)
{
    //Code here ???
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to send files to server before save *Customer*. Your main view model (like `CustomerViewModel`) can contain `List<CustomerFileViewModel> CustomerFiles`.

In popup when you added a file, you need to add `CustomerFileViewModel` to `CustomerFiles`.

Comment: yes, no need to send file to server before save customer. how we can handle that?

Comment: @Aziz you have a model that includes first name, last name, status, phone etc. Add `CustomerFileViewModel` or `CustomerFileViewModel[]` to the model. 
Do not submit popup when you clicked to *Add File* button. *Add File* button need to call a javascript function. So create a javascript function. That function must create inputs *display:none* with data from popup.